# Use XSL to select value of non-unique element with unique attribute

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

I have a XML file like the below, where there are multiple elements with the same name, but different 'name' attributes.

```
<doc>
    <sub1>
        <vdf:field name="asset.title">
            <vdf:value>XYZTITLE</vdf:value>
        </vdf:field>
        <vdf:field name="asset.type">
            <vdf:value>XYZTYPE</vdf:value>
        </vdf:field>
    </sub1>
</doc>
```

I need to parse this using an XML stylesheet. If the element names in the XML file were all unique, I would be able to use something like -

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="doc/sub1/uniqueelement != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="doc/sub1/uniqueelement"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>Undefined</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

How can I modify the above XSL to select the value of "XYZTITLE" in the "vdf:field" element where name="asset.title"?

Comment: There is no `uniqueelement` in the given input. And the input is not XML: you cannot have an unbound prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates). For example, for the following XML:

```
<doc>
    <sub1>
        <field name="asset.title">
            <value>XYZTITLE</value>
        </field>
        <field name="asset.type">
            <value>XYZTYPE</value>
        </field>
    </sub1>
</doc>
```

the instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/doc/sub1/field[@name='asset.title']/value"/>
```

will return:

```
XYZTITLE
```

Comment: I found that I also needed to declare the namespace 'vdf' in my XLS in order for the vdf:field and vdf:value elements to work properly. i.e. xmlns:vdf="http://example.com"

Comment: You're learning fast. After a few months, your fingers will start to type "XSL" instead of "XLS".